# UISnapBehavior Causing Distortion

Tags: ios, objective-c

For whatever reason, whenever I use the snapping behavior, it causes the UIButtons to turn into rectangles of various sizes when "snapped". I'm probably just looking right over the issue. My deadline is tomorrow to get the last bugs worked out, so I would GREATLY appreciate ANY help! Thank you!

vvv - ViewController.m - vvv

```
//set points
CGPoint bullyboxPoint = {80, 188};
CGPoint weemPoint = {240, 188};
CGPoint yeaPoint = {80, 339};
CGPoint charityPoint = {240, 339};
CGPoint phhsPoint = {80, 488};
CGPoint experiencePoint = {240, 488};

//make the buttons closer to speed up the snap
bullybox.frame = CGRectMake(40, 788, 120, 120);
weem.frame = CGRectMake(200, 788, 120, 120);
yea.frame = CGRectMake(30, 939, 120, 120);
charity.frame = CGRectMake(190, 939, 120, 120);
phhs.frame = CGRectMake(20, 1328, 120, 120);
experience.frame = CGRectMake(180, 1328, 120, 120);

//create behaviors
UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self->bullybox snapToPoint:bullyboxPoint];
UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior1 = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self->weem snapToPoint:weemPoint];
UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior2 = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self->yea snapToPoint:yeaPoint];
UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior3 = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self->charity snapToPoint:charityPoint];
UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior4 = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self->phhs snapToPoint:phhsPoint];
UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior5 = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self->experience snapToPoint:experiencePoint];

//dampen the snap
snapBehavior.damping = 1.2f;
snapBehavior1.damping = 1.2f;
snapBehavior2.damping = 1.2f;
snapBehavior3.damping = 1.2f;
snapBehavior4.damping = 1.2f;
snapBehavior5.damping = 1.2f;

//add behaviors
[self.animator addBehavior:snapBehavior];
[self.animator addBehavior:snapBehavior1];
[self.animator addBehavior:snapBehavior2];
[self.animator addBehavior:snapBehavior3];
[self.animator addBehavior:snapBehavior4];
[self.animator addBehavior:snapBehavior5];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're using Autolayout. Autolayout and UIKit Dynamics are enemies (if you look at Apple's example code, you'll see that they have circumvented this issue by turning Autolayout off).

The way I like to solve this problem is: Make snapshot images of the objects to be animated; hide the actual objects and put the snapshot images in their place; animate the snapshot images; when it's all over, take the snapshot images out of the interface and show the actual objects in their new location.

This works because the snapshot images are not subject to Autolayout. However, you will *still* need to grapple with the issue, because you cannot move buttons that are subject to Autolayout by setting their `frame`; you must set their *constraints*.